# How to pass user data to EF Core interceptor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Is it possible to obtain user data in EF Core interceptor? I would like to somehow pass it from the outside, but not sure if it is possible.

```
 public class AuditingInterceptor : SaveChangesInterceptor
 {
     public override ValueTask<InterceptionResult<int>> SavingChangesAsync(
        DbContextEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<int> result,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        //how to get user data here?
    }
}
```

Comment: Add property to your `DbContext` and pass everything that you need via that property. So basically it is enough to create some `AuditedDbContextBase` with desired property. `DbContextEventData` contains `Context ` property - just cast to `AuditedDbContextBase`.

Comment: You can also do something like this, 
`
private readonly ICurrentUserService _currentUserService;

    public AuditingInterceptor(ICurrentUserService currentUserService)
    {
        _currentUserService = currentUserService;
    }
`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what user info you need to pass. But here's an example to access current user information.

```
public class AuditingInterceptor: SaveChangesInterceptor
{
    private readonly ICurrentUserService _currentUserService;

    public AuditingInterceptor(ICurrentUserService currentUserService)
    {
        _currentUserService = currentUserService;
    }


    public override ValueTask<InterceptionResult<int>> SavingChangesAsync(DbContextEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<int> result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        // some logic
    }
}

// The implementation for ICurrentUserService to get user info
public class CurrentUserService : ICurrentUserService
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public CurrentUserService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public string? UserId => _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
    public string? UserName => _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name);
}

// Register the DI
services.AddSingleton<ICurrentUserService, CurrentUserService>();
```

I hope this helps.